# Looking to get count of ID for entity that has an answer to two separate questions, in the same row - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am working on a project where I have a data set that includes `ID, Question Name, Answer`.  This is all being built into Power BI report.  I am trying to get the count of distinct `ID`'s where for each `ID` or entity I have multiple answers.

For example I have Session ID 12345, and for this session we conduct an outcome survey that asks the questions 'What was your focus area?' and 'Overall how satisfied were you with your coach?'

Now I have a group of Sessions, all unique, and this group has Answered 'Healthy Eating to the first question (focus area).  Within this group I want to find the count that has answered 'Satisfied' or 'Very Satisfied'.

I have already gotten the count for the group of Sessions that have answered healthy eating:

```
found Session Count first:
Session Count = Calculate(distinctcount(SessionID))
```

Then applied filter for Healthy Eating:

```
healthy eating = calculate([Session Count]), FILTER(Table1, Table1[Answer]="Healthy Eating"))
```

Now I thought I could get the Satisfied and Very Satisfied count by using the following:

```
HE Satisfied = calculate([healthy eating]), (FILTER(Table1, Table1[Answer] = "Satisfied" || Table1[Answer]= "Very Satisifed"))
```

I am getting blank value.

Table struture is like the below example:

```
SessionID      QuestionName                             Answer
123            What was your focus area?                Healthy Eating
123            Overall how satisfied were you with      Very Satisfied
               your coach?
124            What was your focus area?                Healthy Eating
124            Overall how satisfied were you with      Very Satisfied
               your coach?
125            What was your focus area?                Healthy Eating
125            Overall how satisfied were you with      Not Satisfied
               your coach?
```

So in the case above, I have a count of 3 Sessions for Healthy Eating, my satisfaction rate would be 2/3 or 67% in this case.  The Math is easy I just need to figure out how to get the Count of 2 from the above.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have to do more data wrangling for this to work.

In your example there's no relationship between session ID 123 regarding focus and session ID 123 regarding coach satisfaction, therefore when you calculate healthy eating you get the correct count but when you try to apply that to the satisfaction levels you get blanks.

If you separate the data into 2 tables one with all "what was your focus area? " rows and the other with the "Overall how satisfied were you with... " rows and then create a relationship between the two on the session ID you'll get the result you're looking for with

```
HE Satisfied = CALCULATE([healthy eating], coach[answer] = "Satisfied" || coach[answer] = "Very Satisfied")
```